# CRON: Run job on particular hours

Tags: spring, cron, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application and i am using CRON to set how often this application runs. But the problem i am running into is that i want to run the job on specific hours

```
3 am
7 am
11 am
3 pm
7 pm
11 pm
```

As you can see it is every 4 hours but starts at 3 am so i cannot use `*/4` in the hours section of the timing format as this would start the job at 4am

I have also tried `'3,7,11,15,19,23'` in the hours section but this does not work either (guessing it only works in the minutes section). Does someone know how i can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
@Scedule(cron="0 0 3/4 * * ?")
```

*The Pattern `x/y` means: where `<timepart> mod y = x`*

or

```
@Scedule(cron="0 0 3,7,11,15,19,21 * * ?")
```

---

According to the [Quartz Cron Trigger Tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06):

> The '/' character can be used to specify increments to values. For
>   example, if you put '0/15' in the Minutes field, it means 'every 15th
>   minute of the hour, starting at minute zero'. If you used '3/20' in
>   the Minutes field, it would mean 'every 20th minute of the hour,
>   starting at minute three' - or in other words it is the same as
>   specifying '3,23,43' in the Minutes field. Note the subtlety that
>   "/35" does *not mean "every 35 minutes" - it mean "every 35th minute
>   of the hour, starting at minute zero" - or in other words the same as
>   specifying '0,35'.

Answer (score 1):

> 0 0 3,7,11,15,19,23 * * ?

Fires  for 0 minute starting at 3am and ending at 23:00 pm every day.

Answer (score 1):

judging by the two answers above the error i was making was i was keeping the apostrophe at the start and end of my hours... very silly

i managed to solve this by using `3-23/4` for the hour as this starts from 3am and then every other fourth hour (just a different way of doing it to the other answers)